# Web - Add to Home Screen not maintaining current page

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications

I'm building a web app which has a login page that I've added a script to allow the user to Add to Home Screen and it opens up fullscreen without the safari toolbars.

However once you pass the first page (login screen) and go to any other screen, if you press the home button and put the app to the background and then re-enter, it kicks you back out to the first login page.

Could anyone shed some light on what is happening there?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any kind of session in each screen to tracked logged in user?

Comment: @TapasPal Yes we have a session running for that

Comment: Then there is a high chance that when ever your application is entering background system terminate the app and then re-enter app is relaunched.

Comment: @TapasPal Ok, I guess because it's running in Safari that I don't have any control over what happens when that occurs. Ok thanks. I guess I could start tracking what page the user is currently on and then push them back there from the login screen.